# Running Laravel sail on a different default path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail

Is it possible to run Laravel sail on a different default path?
Currently expects /var/www/html/ but my distro uses /srv/http

error message:
The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

I have tried changing the docker-compose.yml to the new path with no success

Answer (score 0):

Sail is just docker, so look in your docker file and find the path, then modify it.

Comment: already tried that

Comment: @JackJones Just to be clear, did you change the WORKDIR variable, as seen here: https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/Dockerfile